Is it informally acceptable to make words like enemies, houses, rock, and them into contractions like this?
For example:

“Watch your six ‘cause the enemies’ll try and sneak up on ya”

“In California all the houses’re 45ft tall”

“Don’t shake the ceiling fan or else that rock’ll fall on you”

“Are all the tenants here sleeping? Yes all of them’re sleeping”



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I suspect this will end in closure on the grounds of "opinion"... Nevertheless, and referring to direct speech only:

“Watch your six ‘cause the enemies’ll try and sneak up on ya” / “Don’t shake the ceiling fan or else that rock’ll fall on you”

The "noun'll" / "nominative pronoun'll" form is always acceptable.

“In California all the houses’re 45ft tall” / “Are all the tenants here sleeping? Yes all of them’re sleeping”.

I can find no examples of this (or "us're") in Google Books (but that may be because of its habit of ignoring punctuation) and can't recall seeing it. However, it appears to be a form of eye-dialect that has simply been overlooked, but is, in fact, useful and appropriate in accurately reflecting unemphasised words in speech.
In short, I think it is acceptable, and is thought to be unacceptable only because it is not currently done and for no better reason.
